# Best Practises for Ui Updation with high volume data post async task completion in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

UI updation happens inside the onPostExecute() of asynctask. So when huge data has to be updated onto the UI there seems to be a slight UI hang or in my case updated by a no of async tasks.

To reproduce this issue, Use a large no of async tasks to add data to a number of Fragments in a tabbed activity. Let each tab have the same fragment with a list to which data is updated.

The effect is evident when the async tasks are executing and you try to switch tabs.
(I have this problem in my whats app too, while am flooded with more than 1000 messages at a single go)

What are the best practices while dealing with updation of ui with large data?

Comment: If you are getting the data from server, don't wait for all the data to arrive and accumulate. Update it as soon as you receive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is "just don't".

How many data can fit the screen? If it's an Image: few MBs, if it's text: few kBs.

Don't update anything user is not seeing. Keep all the data you need in model and update only when visible. ListView and Adapter is a really good example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Use database to keep your data. There's no problem populating database in `onBackground()` and no point populating UI with 1000 messages if only say 6 or 10 would fit the screen at once